# Django and nginx do not accept PATCH requests, resulting in a 400 bad request error

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-rest-framework

I work on a Django project + django-rest-framework. On localhost, PATCH requests work **perfectly fine**. However, on server, PATCH requests do not work. I get a *400 Bad request* error. I use nginx to configure the web server.

Here is my configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name x.y.z.com;
    root /var/www/path-to/project;

    location / {
            error_page 404 = 404;
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5555/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
    }
}
```

I get this error when I try PATCH requests on server :

[image]

How can I make so that django accept PATCH requests? The log does not show anything. As if it does not even receives the request. I run the django server like this:

```
python manage.py runserver 5555
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Friend, I faced this problem, I made all the possible settings in nginx, but the problem was in my js fetch that tried with the patch method in lowercase, 'patch', changing to 'PATCH' worked normally.

Comment: This is crazy. How the hell was I supposed to know that, thank you friend it now works like a charm!

Comment: My god, I must have spent a good few hours trying to figure out why only on non-local environments this kept happening. All because it was uppercase... unbelievable.

Comment: Strange that `get` & `post` worked.